# Different approaches to classification of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Currently, I'm approaching the problem of finite group classification, in particular I'm studying group cohomology. I know that to achieve this result one path mathematicians are actually working on is the *Hölder* program concerning group extensions and their classification. I was wondering if there exist other approches to this problem, in particular using subgroups lattices or subnormal subgroups lattices or representations.

Comment: The classification of the finite simple groups was an extremel difficult task , but now we actually know all of them. However, the classification of the finite groups is hopeless. Beginning with the simple groups is surely the best approach because every group can be built up by them.

Comment: Don't use mathmode (`$text$`) to fake italics. You can surround text with a single asterisk and that will create italic text.

Comment: (and mark-up can be used to produce differently accented letters; `&ouml;` produces the o with the umlaut)

Comment: Cohomology allows you to classify group extensions. But two group extensions might be inequivalent and at the same time result in isomorphic groups. Still, it is a step in the right direction. Of course, the classification of finite simple groups has to be taken for granted.